# Getting bad request from parse on multiple logins required before queries

Tags: parse-platform

I have ten REST methods that access my data on Parse.com. Every table is secured by `Role` and I have only one user in that role and use it to fetch data from server.

So each method before every query use parse method `LoginAsync()`. As I call these methods very often sometimes login failed with bad request error from Parse for some methods.

I wonder is the multiple logins issue here and what is better strategy to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

After logging in, Parse.com does provide a way for you to use information from the logged in user. Therefore, you don't have to make multiple request for logging in. The only reason you need to call it again is: you log out before.

For your case, I think you should implement your own version of cookie. Then, you are not necessarily to call log-in api in order to get user information.

Comment: But theese are rest methods and I have multiple web clients that use it this is why I can't store it like on an android app for example. I also tried with tokens but again sometimes it work and sometimes it return bad request and requests are completly equal. Is it possible that parse restrict me to call 10 methods from some reason?

Comment: For the free version, you can call 30 request per second. Then, you need to have your own mechanism to cache the logged user. It does not make sense also whenever you need that you call the log-in API.